# Saving a file from a website path linking the file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export an excel file from a website. The path that I am provided already clicks the export the file and opens a prompt that asks what I want to do with the file. How do I access the prompt box to open the file?

I've tried the code where you open the path to the google gif but it doesn't work with this since the path doesn't really lead to my content. My goal is to open the excel file and export the content to my main excel file (the one containing the macro).

Ive tried this but this only works on direct link to content and not to saving prompt.

```
Function SaveWebFile(ByVal vWebFile As String, ByVal vLocalFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte

     'You can also set a ref. to Microsoft XML, and Dim oXMLHTTP as MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False 'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.send 'send request

     'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array

     'Create local file and save results to it
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF

     'Clear memory
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

This works if the path is the web content itself. I need work from a path that initiates download of the file. Thanks!